# barely held together through the estimated 800 hours it took to record Déjà Vu

Tags: meaning-in-context

*Those achievements are all the more astonishing given the fact that the group **barely held together through the estimated 800 hours it took to record Déjà Vu** and scarcely functioned as a group for most of that time.*

https://www.allmusic.com/album/d%C3%A9j%C3%A0-vu-mw0000193436

I am not able to catch the precise meaning of the bolded passage. Does it mean that the recording of the mentioned album lasted 800 hours?

Comment: It means that the group was always on the edge of breaking up during the recording of the album, which was estimated to take 800 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question: yes, it means that the recording of the mentioned album did indeed take *(an estimated)* 800 person-hours. Assuming that the group is working 8 hours a day, that's over three months. If this seems long, the fact that the group was "barely held together" might be an excellent reason why; how much of that time was spent just keeping the the band from flying apart at the proverbial seams?

Comment: Estimated 800 hours.